# set background image in spinner view android

Tags: android, view, background, android-spinner

I want to set a background image on my spinner.  Problem is , when I apply image to spinner, the height of the spinner stretches as per image size (which off course I do not want). I want that image should fit in the spinner view (as we can easily do in imagebutton view) Following example is one of my tries.

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btnmusic"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

I have also changed the scaletype with all available options but it does not work.

Can I fix it in xml or I need to do it programmatically?

Answer (score -1):

1. You can set the android:layout_width and android:layout_height attributes to specific size (better in dp units).
2. See in the [android sdk folder]\android-sdks\platforms\android-#\data\res\drawable
   the actual size of spinner images and resize yours.
3. Also see spinner [custom selector](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57)

Comment: it works fine if i set the spinner height in dp. but as you know that because of different screen sizes and densities, the view size should be wrap_content...

Comment: In that case you can add different dimensions to value folder in [resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html)